# Localization in OpenSocial gadget app

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, opensocial

I'm trying to add multi-language support to an OpenSocial application. I see that I can link to my own message bundles in the gadget XML markup:

```
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Hello" description="Message bundle demo">
     <Require feature="opensocial-0.7"/>
     <Locale lang="en" messages="http://example.com/hello/en_ALL.xml"/>
  </ModulePrefs>
  . . .
</Module>
```

But how do I actually extract values from them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the values you should use the [getMsg](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/docs/0.7/reference/gadgets.Prefs.html#getMsg) method

```
var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
var msg = prefs.getMsg('hello_world');
```